# SSIS Changing Name attribute of packages

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

In my project they have changed the naming convention of package name attribute to be "Package Name (Project Name)" from just "Package Name". This attribute is eventually used by our Notification framework to send out the error and success emails, hence the change to distinguish between packages with the same name from different projects. So my question is - Is there an easy way to do this .. Or do I need to open each package and change the attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening each package is by far the safest thing to do.

We have had success using Notepad++ to do a global find-replace on each solution our local TFS directory, but this will break your packages nearly as often as update them.  If you have a LOT of packages, you could try to write a C# console app that would do this, but I doubt it would be worth it unless you had more than 100 packages and needed to change the names more than once.

Get some fresh coffee and engage in some drudgery.

Comment: Yep.. that looks like sound advice... Something to do with my Saturday morning coffee.. :)